# Visual Studio 2017 - Disable Provide Feedback Notifications

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

Is there a way to disable to constant "Provide feedback" notifications in Visual Studio 2017. I keep hitting "Always Ignore" but they persist.

[image]

Edit: Tried Help --> Send Feedback --> Settings. Changed setting to "No, I would not like to participate" but continue to receive "Provide feedback" notifications.

Edit 2: For my situation this may be due to Resharper ([link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466271)) which was reported on the MS Developer Community site ([link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110213/stop-sending-provide-feedback-notification-over-an.html)). I'll update the question again once I've confirmed.

Edit 3: **Disabled Resharper and no notifications ... yet. Re-enabled Resharper 2017.2 and instantly reappeared after relaunching VS.** Seems to be 1 notification for each instance of VS running.

Edit 4: Posted answer below. Was caused by using Resharper 2017.2 in evaluation mode.

Comment: I resolved this temporarily by fully uninstalling and cleaning VS files, then installing a prior release of VS 2017. I used the following URL: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202017  and selected Enterprise 15.0 (not 15.3 even though the release dates suggest 15.3 is older than 15.0 -- they are misleading/mislabeled). This has worked for me for now, until MS releases a fix. If trying the same, you will need to be logged into your MSDN account to download the prior release.

Comment: You should add this comment as an answer. I'll try downgrading my VS version when I have time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case it was 100% caused by Resharper (version 2017.2) when using in "Evaluation" mode. Once I entered license info (via a JB account) the notifications went away. To confirm this I logged out, restarted the evaluation, closed/reopened VS and notifications were instantly back. Logged back in via a JB account, restarted and notifications went away.

It seems that @MachinusX is receiving notifications for a different reason so they should post a new question with their details since my issue has been resolved.

Comment: The only change in my environment prior to this issue, was an update to Visual Studio. Reverting to the prior release has resolved my issue until the next release of VS. I am using Resharper again successfully and with or without that product, the issue occurred. If I persist in investigating a resolution, I won't get work done, so my workaround of reverting is what I have to stick with.

Answer (score 3):

Taking suggestion of @KornMuffin and adding my comment as an answer:

I resolved this temporarily by fully uninstalling and cleaning VS files, then installing a prior release of VS 2017. I used the following URL: [VS 2017 Releases](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202017) and selected Enterprise 15.0 (not 15.3 even though the release dates suggest 15.3 is older than 15.0 -- they are misleading/mislabeled). This has worked for me for now, until MS releases a fix. If trying the same, you will need to be logged into your MSDN account to download the prior release.

Comment: Did you try disabling Resharper? That's the cause of the notifications in my case. I guess I'll have to wait for a Resharper fix.

Comment: Yes. I fully removed Resharper and each and EVERY optional extension, to no avail. Further, the issue only began appearing after a single change: the latest VS 2017 update. Resharper did not change, but VS did. Regardless, though, I did remove each add-on, and no, it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @KornMuffin Am curious: how did you arrive at the conclusion that Resharper is the cause? Did this not happen after the VS update? I ask because as I mentioned a few times prior, I removed Resharper entirely and rebooted et cetera, and the Visual Studio feedback notifications were still present and still very buggy.

Comment: For me was due to Resharper in evaluation mode

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opting for "non participation", click on "Don't show again" link on the pop-up. This seems to have solved the issue as mentioned at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63752/vs2017-requests-feedback-then-tells-me-ive-already.html

Comment: Thanks. Will try the next time I get a notification.

Comment: Tried that first, of course, and any other option I could find. Saved/exited, rebooted, restarted VS, and BAM. Here it comes again.

Comment: So as to preclude any other tips for basic end-users: I mean...we are developers.  We all automatically try every option, right? That is why I have joined @KornMuffin in this question...because am an atypical end-user, and this requires something beyond standard tech-support replies. And I am so not trying to be impolite...not my goal at all. Am frustrated with my dev environment right now, not with your helpful tips.

Comment: @MachinusX are you using and VS plugins (ex. Resharper, coderush ... etc)?

Comment: @KornMuffin I have received this notification both with and without extensions. I removed all of them I restarted Visual Studio and notifications still there. I uninstalled Visual Studio made sure no extensions were added ... rebooted restarted visual-studio... notifications still there. Happens with or without extensions. yes I am an avid user and lover of resharper. However I fully removed it from my system and this notifications still occurs.

Comment: The machine this is occurring on is a Windows 7 machine. It does not happen on my other development machine which is a Windows 10 machine. The other difference is that the machine this is happening on is full of Group Policy Scripts and virtualization apps from the company that I am working for.

Answer (score 2):

Normally that kind of option, when marked, is saved somewhere in Regedit so whenever the popup is about to appear again it will check first what options you have marked. 
If it's not remembering them, maybe it's an issue saving your preferences? 
Somtimes it can be just as simple as running visual with administrator priviledges.
 I say this because mine kept forgetting my account and I had to sign in every single time I opened it.
 
Switched to running it with administrator priviledges and it no longer forgets me which is so much better than having to put my credentials every single time!

Comment: I am running as an administrator as my default (I set it in the Advanced properties dialog of the shortcut tab). One of the things I first tried, was to disable running as admin, and I launched VS as a standard user. Neither has resolved this issue.

Comment: I believe this is solely due to the latest VS update, and I think one of their devs changed something that affected the feedback notification feature. All was fine prior to this update, and I changed nothing in my system, save for that VS update.

Comment: Good luck then, mine is up to date but I don't get the same issue, I'm using VS Enterprise 2017 version 15.3.26730.16 and windows 10 pro version 1703 in case that is of any use to you

Comment: Thank you, @Alan Warden for your reply. I have VS 2017 latest update on multiple machines. One is a Windows 10 Pro machine and it runs fine. The machine I was experiencing issues with 2017 on, is a Windows 7 machine. I cannot change that environment as it is work for a client, and requires I use their machine with their constraints. At any rate, my workaround for now on that Win 7 machine, is to use the prior VS 2017 release as nothing else I tried sufficed. I do wish large corporations would update their systems, but wishing does nothing.